# ReactJS: How to test for a ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

This is a function used in a react component. As you can see I'm using ref to get the focus on a specific input element of another component.

```
myFunction (param) {
  this.refInput && this.refInput.focus()
}
```

Now I would like to test via jestJS for the `focus()` to have been called.

```
it('myFunction() should call focus()', () => {
  // SETUP
  const refInput = { focus: jest.fn() }
  wrapper = shallow(<Example
    refInput={refInput}
  />)
  // EXECUTE
  wrapper.instance().myFunction('anything')
  // VERIFY
  expect(refInput.focus).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

But this is wrong, as I pass the `refInput` as a property. But it is **not** `this.props.refInput`, so this attempt is not working.

How do I setup a ref in my test?

---

**Update**

This is how my component looks like:

```
class Example extends Component {
  setStep (state) {
    state.term = ''
    this.setState(state)
    this.refInput && this.refInput.focus()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Step onClick={this.setStep.bind(this, this.state)}>
          <Step.Content title='title' description='description' />
        </Step>
        <Input ref={input => { this.refInput = input }} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: shallow rendering does not maintain the internal instance and therefore it can't hold a ref. I think in order to test a ref you have to mount the component. Have a look at the MountedRenderer

Comment: which version of react are you using? if 15.4.0 or heigher then have a look at this: https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html#mocking-refs-for-snapshot-testing. If you explicitly want to test DOM nodes you have to use Enzime (http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/ref.html)

Comment: @MarouenMhiri I'm using React 16 and Enzyme...

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
it('myFunction() should call focus()', () => {
  // SETUP
  wrapper = mount(<Example />)
  // EXECUTE
  wrapper.instance().myFunction('anything')
  // VERIFY
  const elem = wrapper.find('#foo'); 
  const focusedElement = document.activeElement;
  expect(elem.matchesElement(focusedElement)).to.equal(true);
})
```

Points to note:

1. Use Mount rather than Shallow, as @Marouen Mhiri commented, shallow rendering can't hold a ref
2. You don't need to pass ref as props (in fact it's wrong)
3. Where I have wrapper.find('#foo'), replace foo by class/id of the DOM element in Input

Comment: I understand your code, but in my case the input element can't be identified by an ID. It just has a class, as there are many elements like this needed. That's why I'm using refs.

Comment: Sure, in that case use wrapper.find('.yourClass'), I understand you said there are many elements with this class, but can we assume that there is only 1 inside each <Component /> ? since we are finding within the context of the mounted component

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the render method of the component ? just to see how it is structured

Comment: Could we replace #foo by class/id of a dom element inside the Input component in this case?

Comment: Yes, I think we can add a class

Comment: any luck with this approach ?

Comment: I'm still learning the whole testing stuff... There would be still a coverage gap for the line `<Input ref={input => { this.refInput = input }} />` -> function not covered. I understand the approach with `document.activeElement`, but for my understanding: It is not possible to test directly for `this.refInput`?

Comment: Since `wrapper` is an instance of `Example`, you could always access the instance variables and test that way too. If you want to test the line you specified, you could try testing that wrapper.refInput .toBeDefined() ?