# Test fails after mounting react component and testing its ref. I'm using jasmine, karma and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, karma-runner, enzyme

I'm trying to write a test for my React component, but I don't know how to proceed.

I have the following:

```
 ...omitted code

  render() {
    const {
      center,
      defaultZoom,
      location
    } = this.props;

    return (

      <GoogleMap
        className="google-map"
        defaultZoom={defaultZoom}
        defaultCenter={center}
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.mapRef = ref;
        }}
      >
        <Marker position={new window.google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng)} />
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
 ...omitted code
```

I have tried different things, but I keep getting either `Expected false to be true` or it just tells me that te tests fails, but without giving me a reason:

```
    it('displays a google map with the right ref', () => {
      // const html = wrapper.html();
      const mountedNode = mount(<SchedulerMap />);
      // expect(wrapper.find(SchedulerMap).hasClass('google-map')).toBe(true);
      // expect(mountedNode.find(SchedulerMap).hasClass('google-map')).toBe(true);
      // expect(mountedNode.find(SchedulerMap).ref()).equals(wrapper.instance().props.mapRef);
      expect(mountedNode.ref('mapRef')).to.notBe(null);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS: How to test for a ref?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049533/reactjs-how-to-test-for-a-ref)

Comment: no not a duplicate. Or at least I don't think so :)